# Unable to get sound working. Ubuntu Server 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, server, sound, alsa, soundcard

I have had this problem for a while now. I have looked around in many places for solutions. But none have worked.

The OS is running on an old Sony Vaio Laptop, model: VPCEB3F4E.

I have used the alsa information script to gather info.
Output is here:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=48f08f47664104fbec921ac7d0be4ca94be3ef35

When running the script the following is displayed before it saves the file:

```
cat: /proc/asound/version: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/alsactl: save_state:1590: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.2TnPpLYBxa/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
```

I have tried adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

To the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf but it doesn't help.

I have tried reinstalling the modules and alsa files using the large command:

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Except ofc editing it to remove desktop gui elements as I am on a server.

I have tried adding myself to the audio group.

I have tried deleting alsa-base.conf, purging alsa-base and reinstalling it.

I have tried looking in the bios to see if anything is disabled. But as with most laptop BIOS options, they suck. Only able to change time, boot order, and C3/C6 support for the CPU.

I have had some progress manually loading snd_hda_intel using:

```
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel
```

That at least gets me an audio device and some more entries under /dev/snd but when playing a file its just static that I hear.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by manually loading snd_hda_intel, accessing volume settings by typing alsamixer at the console and then turning down the volumes from the red area. This seems to have stopped the sound from being all static.

These levels were then saved by issuing the command:

```
sudo alsactl store
```

The module was set to load at boot by adding:

```
snd_hda_intel
```

to the list in:

```
/etc/modules
```

To do that I used nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

I could've swore I tried messing with the volume before, but oh well, its working now =D